# how to change date format in java from "yyyy-mm-dd" to "dd-mm-yyyy"

Tags: java, class, methods, time, localdate

i used the class localDAte in a method like this :

```
public String dateR(int ageR) {
        LocalDate dateR= dateN.plusYears(ageR);
        return dateR.toString();
}
```

and it gives me the date in "yyyy-mm-dd" format however i want it in "dd-mm-yyyy" format

i want the result date in "dd-mm-yyyy" format

Comment: `return dateR.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu", Locale.ROOT));`. Or for many purposes even better `dateR.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT))` to get the localized format for the default locale. Under all circumstances extract the formatter into a constant.